# how can i use zeromq to broadcast on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, zeromq

i just wrote a very simple python script like this

server side:

```
import zmq
import time

cxt = zmq.Context()
s=cxt.socket(zmq.SUB)
s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:1900")

while True:
   s.send("CMD:once")
   print "send once"
   time.sleep(1)
```

and the client side:

```
import zmq
import time

cxt = zmq.Context()
s = cxt.socket(zmq.SUB)

s.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:1900")
s.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,'')

while True:
    msg = s.recv()
    print msg

print "Done".
```

i works when i use 127.0.0.1 in my client side script.but when i use the public network ip address,my client script can not receive any message.

both two scripts run on the VPS(amazon web service).

do i need some settings on AWS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the *private* IP of the EC2 instance.  Public IPs in EC2 are provided by NAT mapping and an instance cannot see itself that way.

You can also use the *public* DNS hostname, as seen in the console, because it will resolve to the private IP when queried internally and the public IP when queried externally.